# How to set many "not contains" condition on Firebase RemoteConfig?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I try to set "App version" condition with not contains "2.0.2" and "2.1.0". 
However, I can not set multiple "App version" while I click "AND" button.
[image]

Next, I try to use "regular expression" and always fail. However, I always fail. Even I try to set "all contains", still fail.
[image]

How can I do for condition with not contains two strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enter both strings separated by comma:

"App version does not contain 2.0.2,2.1.0"

(documented in https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters)